# How to translate english to swedish using dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am using following code, but showing some error - index out of range

```
english=["merry", "christmas", "and", "happy", "new", "year"]
swedish=["god","jul","och","gott","nytt","år"]
dict = {english[n]: swedish[n] for n in range(len(english))}#dictionary
trans_list=[]#list to save translated words

def trans(list):
    n=0
    for word1 in list:    
        for word2 in english: 
            if word1==word2:             
                       trans_list[n]=dict[word2]
                       n=n+1
                       print trans_list                 
list2=[]
list =["merry", "christmas", "and", "happy", "new", "year"]
trans(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to your problem:

```
english = ["merry", "christmas", "and", "happy", "new", "year"]
swedish = ["god", "jul", "och", "gott", "nytt", "år"]

eng_swe_dict = {english: swedish for english, swedish in zip(english, swedish)}

def trans(word_list):
    return [eng_swe_dict[word] for word in word_list]

word_list = ["merry", "christmas", "and", "happy", "new", "year"]
print trans(word_list)
```

This would display the following:

```
['god', 'jul', 'och', 'gott', 'nytt', 'år']
```

Firstly, you should avoid using variable names such as `dict` and `list` as these are built in Python commands. Python will not complain, but you will reassign the meaning.

Your lookup dictionary could be constructed by using the `zip` command. In this case, it takes one entry from each of your two lists to provide to the loop, which are then used to construct the dictionary.

A Python `list comprehension` can be used to create the translated list. For each word, it translates it and adds it to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

trans_list is defined as a list:

```
trans_list=[]
```

However it is an empty list. So there are no indexes available and the assignment line fails:

```
trans_list[n]=dict[word2]
```

What you can do is simply append the value to the list:

```
trans_list.append(dict[word2])
```